# Retrieve full name from ldap AD

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

This is my LDAP code to authenticate a user. I have to show users full name once the user had logged in. How do I get the full name of the user from AD?

```
<?php
FUNCTION ldapCheckLogin ($username, $upasswd) {

    $ldaphost = '10.20.30.40';   
    $ldapport = 389;
    $ds = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport) 
        or die("Could not connect to our login server!");

    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);

    if ($ds) 
    {
        //$username = 'na\'; //OK - Congratulations! na\spups is authenticated.
        $upname = 'iap\\' . $username;

        $ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ds, $upname, $upasswd);

        if ($ldapbind) {
            //print "Congratulations! $username is authenticated.<BR><BR>";
            ldap_unbind( $ds ); 
            return true;
        } else { //print "$username  - Access Denied!<BR><BR>";
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Seems like some of your code is missing. You might also consider formatting your code for better readability

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the user's entry using ldap_search with the user's `samAccountName`  e.g. `(samaccountname=$username)` or `userPrincipalName` e.g. `(userprincipalname=$username . "@" . $domain.com )` as the filter attribute.

`samaccountname` is only unique in the domain whereas `userPrincipalName` is unique across the entire forest.

When you perform the ldap_search you need to include the `cn` or `displayName` in the attributes to return.

If the search is successful then you need to process the resulting entry and extract the `cn` and/or the `displayName`.

Comment: I would recommend you retrieve givenName and sn as the attributes you return. The cn and displayName may not be populated or in the format you desire. This allow you to display the names as you desire.

Comment: Agreed, i think *user2989676* can probably grab all four attrs and pick what best suits their needs.  `cn` is required but may not have the user's fullname; hard to say what they have in their environment. I can't recall for sure but I think the default value or `displayName` in AD is `givenName + " " + sn`.